# How to change URL hash of WebView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I did load a local single page webapp into a iOS UIWebView.
The html file is loaded via

```
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("index", withExtension:"html", subdirectory: "html")
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
```

How can I set the url hash or search value to not load just

```
.../index.html
```

but for example:

```
.../index.html?flag=test#main
```

Once the html file is loaded, can I change the hash or search value somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i resolve my problem with this code:

On Swift (Native Code) i created the timer listen javascript variable change:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         ...
         var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
                  0.4,
                  target: self,
                  selector: #selector(ViewController.update), //#call method
                  userInfo: nil,
                  repeats: true)
```

Use this method (#call method) to listen the javascript variable:

```
   var pathCurrent: String!;    
   func update() {

       let path: String! = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("var path = public.path;  (function(_path){return _path;})(path)")

        if (path != pathCurrent)
        {
            //path changed
            print(path);

            pathCurrent = path;
        }

            print(path);
        }
    }
```

Note, this code, read the *public variable* ->
**var path = public.path;**

Now, in Angular JS, you can change the public variable when route was changed:

```
$scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function($currentRoute, $previousRoute) {
     public.path = $location.$$path;    
});
```

Or you can detect via JavaScript:

```
window.onhashchange = function() {  
    public.path = location.href.substr(path.indexOf("#/")+1);
}
```

now you know when angular path was changed in your native swift code :D